# AngularJS ng-repeat filter specific nested property

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filtering

I am trying to filter an ngRepeat by a specific array attribute.

js:

```
app.controller('UserIndexController', function ($scope, $http, $window) {

    $scope.search = {};

    $http({ method: 'GET', url: '/api/v2/group' })
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

            $scope.groups = data;

        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

        });

    $http({ method: 'GET', url: '/api/v2/user' })
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

            $scope.users = data;

        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

        });
});
```

html:

```
<div data-ng-controller="UserIndexController">
<select 
    ng-model="search.group" 
    ng-options="group.name as group.name for group in groups" 
    class="form-control">
    <option value="">Filter Users by Group</option>
</select>

<table class="table table-responsive table-striped table-hover">
        <thead>
    <tr>
            <th>User Type</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        <th>Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr data-ng-repeat="user in users | filter:search.group">
        <td><% user.groups[0].name %></td>
        <td><% user.last_name %>, <% user.first_name %></td>
        <td><% user.email %></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

The above code searches through the entire user object. This behaviour is not wanted because if any other `user` data attributes match the string in the selected option, then this row will also be included in the filter.

How do I ensure that the filter only works on the `user.groups[0].name` column?

`<tr data-ng-repeat="user in users | filter:{user.groups[0].name: search.group}">` results in the following error: `Syntax Error: Token '[' is unexpected`.

As such, I need something to either put `user.groups[0].name` directly into the user object so that the filter doesn't have to access it via the array, or a way of filtering on the array object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a custom filter function:

```
$scope.groupMatcher = function(groupFilter) {
  return function(user) {
    return user.groups[0].name === groupFilter;
  }
};
```

And use it:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="user in users | filter:groupMatcher('2')">
    {{user.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

If you need this more often define it as a custom filter in your module

Answer (score 0):

First of all: The error is selfspeaking. Filter expects an object to check the items passed to the filter against. You cant use `[]` in object property names.

About your problem: 
So you want to show all users, that belong to a specific group. Maybe with your own filter ?

```
yourApp.filter("UserByGroupNameFilter", function ()
{                
    return function (arrUsers, groupName)
    {
        var resultUsers = [];
        for(var i in arrUsers){
          var user = arrUsers[i];                
            /* Loop for all columns
               for(var j in user.groups){
                 if(user.groups[j].name == groupName){
                     resultUsers.push(user);
                     break;
                }
            } 
            */
          if(user.groups[0].name == groupName){
               resultUsers.push(user);
          }
        }     
        return resultUsers;
    };
});
```